# Proxy Object for getting System Time

Tags: java, guava

There is a pretty cool concept of a [Ticker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Ticker.html) in Guava. Unfortunately, it seems like it was designed around generating nano-second focused Stopwatches for measuring execution durations.

I'd like to find something to use like this because, it makes testing classes sensitive to time changes easier. I have run into an issue historically when I used `System.currentTimeMillis()` because its hard to simulate the passage of time in a test. I was thinking of using a similar interface to what Guava has but measuring times in millis instead since that matches more of the available libraries.

I wanted to ask if anyone has seen something similar or has other suggestions before I go write it myself.

Comment: Wait.  You want a `Ticker`, except measuring times in milliseconds?  Is there any special reason that converting from nanoseconds is a problem?

Comment: @NickCampion: It's not a bad question. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I use in my projects:

```
public interface Clock {
    LocalDate today();
    LocalTime time();
    LocalDateTime now();
    long timestamp();
}
```

As you said it makes unit testing much simpler (or even possible). I have one implementation which always returns the true time and a `FakeClock` that I can control. The implementations of it are so simple that you can easily roll your own - I don't think there's something like it in Guava.

This approach is also described and recommended in [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the idea and for the book reference, look interesting.

Answer (score 5):

As you point out, `Ticker` is for measuring *elapsed* time (what `System.nanoTime()` is for), not wall clock time (what `System.currentTimeMillis()` is for) and you shouldn't use it for getting that.

I'd suggest creating an abstract `Clock` class that's like `Ticker` but for getting wall clock time in millis.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Colin. I am going to mark Christoph the 'answer' even though you guys say the same thing because I ended up using the exact Clock he defined. If I could mark 2 answers, you'd be #2 :) Unfortunately, I also decided to use joda-time so, my clock wouldn't make sense to commit back to guava. Thats a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After further thought, I like the suggestion by Christoph and Colin. The idea of a similar functionality for wall clock would be nice.

As pointed out, the best strategy here is probably just to implement a method which will read a millisecond time off the Ticker.